# SQL Server Silent installation get error during installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, silent-installer, advanced-installer

I want to install SQL Server Express (preferably 2008 or 2014) silently using Advanced Installer. I followed the instructions in two document created by advanced installer online:

[How to Install SQL Server Express](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html) and [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/examples/sqlexpr_after_finish.zip) is a sample *.aip file to show what the settings need to install SQL server Express silently.

**My scenarios:**

Get error during simple installing:

However, I get this error:

[image: during simple installing]

I already test manually SQL Server Express `setup.exe` on the target system. So the file and target system doesn't have any problems.

I'm trying to setup.exe using `ConfigurationFile.ini` as following in command line:
[image: ConfigurationFile.ini]

This is my `ConfigurationFile.ini` code:

```
    ;SQLSERVER2008 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will reflect the instance ID of the SQL Server instance. 

INSTANCEID="BNSDEV"

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter. 

ACTION="Install"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the database engine, replication, and full-text. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online, Business Intelligence Development Studio, and other shared components. 

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION

; Displays the command line parameters usage 

HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console. 

INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="False"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system. 

X86="False"

; Detailed help for command line argument ROLE has not been defined yet. 

ROLE="AllFeatures_WithDefaults"

; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined yet. 

ENU="True"

; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI, and AutoAdvance for a simplied UI. 

UIMODE="Normal"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

ERRORREPORTING="True"

; Specify the root installation directory for native shared components. 

INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the installation directory. 

INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS). 

INSTANCENAME="BNSDEV"

; Agent account name 

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

; Auto-start service after installation.  

AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"

; Startup type for Integration Services. 

ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Account for Integration Services: Domain\User or system account. 

ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"

; Controls the service startup type setting after the service has been created. 

ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; The collation to be used by Analysis Services. 

ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"

; The location for the Analysis Services data files. 

ASDATADIR="Data"

; The location for the Analysis Services log files. 

ASLOGDIR="Log"

; The location for the Analysis Services backup files. 

ASBACKUPDIR="Backup"

; The location for the Analysis Services temporary files. 

ASTEMPDIR="Temp"

; The location for the Analysis Services configuration files. 

ASCONFIGDIR="Config"

; Specifies whether or not the MSOLAP provider is allowed to run in process. 

ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1"

; A port number used to connect to the SharePoint Central Administration web application. 

FARMADMINPORT="0"

; Startup type for the SQL Server service. 

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3). 

FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express. 

ENABLERANU="True"

; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine. 

SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account. 

SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

; Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server system administrators. 

SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS"

; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. 

ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol. 

TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol. 

NPENABLED="0"

; Startup type for Browser Service. 

BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"

; Specifies which account the report server NT service should execute under.  When omitted or when the value is empty string, the default built-in account for the current operating system.
; The username part of RSSVCACCOUNT is a maximum of 20 characters long and
; The domain part of RSSVCACCOUNT is a maximum of 254 characters long. 

RSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

; Specifies how the startup mode of the report server NT service.  When 
; Manual - Service startup is manual mode (default).
; Automatic - Service startup is automatic mode.
; Disabled - Service is disabled 

RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Specifies which mode report server is installed in.  
; Default value: “FilesOnly”  

RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode"
```

I think there must be a problem with `PCUSOURCE`. because as `fig1` I getting an error as The system can not find the file specified and system looking the sqlSupport.msi.
**can anyone help me to solve this problem?**

## Edited

Here is the last summery.txt for installation:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  User cancelled
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068380094
  Exit facility code:            1207
  Exit error code:               1602
  Exit message:                  User has cancelled.
  Start time:                    2017-10-30 13:27:09
  End time:                      2017-10-30 13:43:48
  Requested action:              Install

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  WINDOWS7-PC
  Machine processor count:       2
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x86
  Process architecture:          32 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  Installation location:         c:\3366571280411213122d3a8c\x86\setup\
  Installation edition:          EXPRESS

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       2

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171030_132528\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CUSOURCE:                      
  ENABLERANU:                    True
  ENU:                           True
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    BNSDEV
  INSTANCENAME:                  BNSDEV
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  PCUSOURCE:                     c:\3366571280411213122d3a8c\PCUSOURCE
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           windows7-PC\windows7
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171030_132528\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20171030_132528\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.CancelException
    Message: 
        User has cancelled.
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.Request.Wait()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.UserInterfaceProxy.SubmitAndWait(Request request)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.UserInterfaceProxy.NavigateToWaypoint(String moniker)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.UserInterfaceService.Waypoint(String moniker)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.UIExtension.WaypointAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(TextWriter statusStream, ISequencedAction actionToRun)
```

## Edited After `@herman` asnswer

as `@herman` answer, I deleted `sqlserverExpr.exe` from file and folder then deleted action command from Action too. after that, I add sqlserverExpr.exe from prerequisites, then on `setup File` Tabs configured values as `@herman` said. But I get Error like this:
[image: I get Error like this]

this is my configuration on setup file:
[image]

Comment: Re: adding a password: you cannot prevent administrators of the machine from adding themselves as an SQL Server sysadmin and gaining access that way, so unless you know your users aren't administrators, there's not much point. (Administrators can also simply shut down the server, take the database files and attach them to another instance.)

Comment: and what is your suggestion, please?

Comment: The problem may be not with installation script. I had very similar problem with `MS SQL Server 2016 Dev`. The server was installed and running but `sa` user was not created. I ended up with `FreshStart` option of `Win 10`. It uninstalls everything (but keep user files) to emulate clean installation of Windows. Then the server was installed as charm. 1) Try to install on another PC. 2) Try FreshStart or clean install.

Comment: I don't think so, I test in multi-systems and all of them can't install and same error

Comment: You're doing the installation on 32bit OS are you sure that you are installing the x86 version of SQL Server as well?

Comment: yes because I can manually install it or even using cmd command. the error is strange because tell that can't find sqlsupport.msi

Comment: Give this a look. https://www.mnscug.org/blogs/brian-mason/176-installing-sql-2012-with-a-configuration-file

Comment: as I already said, I don't have any problem with silent installation using direct cmd. I get error while I want to install it using advanced installer

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be much easier for you to add SQL Server as a prerequisite into your project, instead of launching it using a custom action. Advanced Installer has predefined prerequisites for SQL Server Express. Just go to << Prerequisites >> view into your setup project and add from there the desired prerequisite into your project. Then delete the current setup.exe from << Files and Folders >> view and the action added in << Custom Actions >> view.

Comment: can you write your method step by step?

Comment: 1. delete the SQL setup files from << Files and Folders >> view/n
2. delete the action added in << Custom Actions >> view of your setup project
3. in << Prerequisites >> view search through the predefined prerequisites list and select the SQL one; that should be all

Comment: when I add SQL setup.exe to prerequisites, I couldn't find it's setup.exe in 'File and folder'.

Comment: Besides, If I add SQL server express as a prerequisite, I can not add my own configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the EXE setups you added in << files and folders >>.[image]

To add your config file just add the prereq as a file from disk and add the config file as additional file to the prereq.[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I get an error that "Config.ini" does not exist.

Comment: I added my last try as your method. please see that